# Use sap.m.Table growing feature without ODate service

Tags: sapui5

I use XML view, and the inside table as follows

```
<Table id="employeeTable"
    growing="true"
    growingThreshold="2"
    updateStarted="startedLoading"
    updateFinished="finishedLoading"
    showNoData="false"
    growingScrollToLoad="true"
    items="{
        path: '/data'
    }">
    <columns>
        <Column><Text text="Name"/></Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Address"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{name}" />
                <Text text="{address}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

I call backend-side through ajax call. The result is JSON format.
How can I make use of the growing feature without having an OData service?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I dont find out the solution. When I did with `ui.commons`, I used the `ui.commons.paginator` for paging, I send the page number as an offset to backend and create sql statement. With `sap.m`, how can I define the "offset" and send it as an parameter when loadMore event is fired. Then, how to append new result to current data?